# Visuals in PowerBI not interacting properly with graph

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am busy building a dashboard and am running into a very simple (it seems) problem which I can not figure out.
I have a graph displayed per month. If I dont select anything the tables should show the Top/Bottom 10 over all my contracts.

[image: Overall selection]

However when I make a selection of months, the top 10 adjusts correctly but the bottom 10 doesn't.
The only difference between these 2 is a filter on "top" or "bottom".

[image: 2 months selected]

As you can see the selection on the Bottom 10 doesnt change. This is very strange. Even if I copy the top 10 table, the copy reacts the same as the bottom 10 table.

I am hoping this is very simple because it has been frustrating me for hours today :)

Thanks in advance !
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Edit Interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions#:%7E:text=Enable%20Visual%20Interactions%20in%20Power%20BI%201%20Select,to%20all%20of%20the%20other%20...%20See%20More.) to change the visual interactions between the month chart to the top and bottom charts and make them "cross filter" instead of "cross highlight".

Comment: Thanks :) works now ! Glad it was me just not knowing this and not something else